# Alarm Manager is not working in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I need to setup an Alarm in some interval of times. To achieve it I wrote:

## TestFragment class

```
private void setupAlarmManager(){
    AlarmManager manager = manager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(getContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), i, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,1499510100000L, pendingIntent);
    manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,1499510220000L, pendingIntent);
}
```

## AlarmReceiver class

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

I put the debug point at `Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` but nothing happened.

4PM = `1499510100000L`
4:03PM = `1499510220000L`

What Am I doing wrong here? Further I want to add a Local notification in `onReceive` method.

Comment: `4PM = 1499510100000L 4:03PM = 1499510220000L` **WRONG**. These values are the *milliseconds* the alarm manager is supposed to wait since when you run it. It's **not a time value**. By the way, 1499510100000 corresponds to about `47 years and a half`. You probably don't want to wait such a long time to see if your alarm fires... ;)

Comment: where does 1499510100000L  come from? use a calendar instead.

Comment: @Rotwang @Mehran This value might be wrong. I will check it but these values are coming from the database which stores the time in milliseconds using `Java.Util` time library. Can't I use `new Date().getTime()` instead of `Calendar` here?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `Calendar` object to set up the alarm time.

For an alarm at 4PM you could do something like:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
```

Then you set up your `AlarmManager` as you already did but for the last line use:

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Maybe you want to use a repeating Alarm or even a `Handler`

If so you should visit: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Comment: These values are coming from the database which stores the time in milliseconds using `Java.Util` time library. Can't I use `new Date().getTime()` instead of `Calendar` here? Let's I am getting two time (could be more) in milliseconds.

Comment: Because I already have a date in milliseconds and calendar will also do the same thing